# Ionic 3 Form submission not working

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am very new to ionic 3 and angular. with tutorial from googles i have created one login for with form validation in ionic. I followed their complete steps even after that mine form doesn't get submitted. I really cant find where is the issue.

My code is here
In the  `login.ts`

```
import {FormBuilder,FormGroup,Validators,FormControl} from "@angular/forms";

export class LoginPage {
  loginForm:FormGroup;
  responseData:any;
  userData={"provider":"web","email":"","password":""};
  constructor(public nav: NavController,
              public forgotCtrl: AlertController,
              public menu: MenuController,
              public toastCtrl: ToastController
  ) {


    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
          password: new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(8)]),
          email: new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(".+\@.+\..+")])
    });
  this.menu.swipeEnable(false);
  }

  login() {
    //Get email address and password and validate
    if(this.loginForm.valid ){
        console.log('do authentication');
      }else{
        console.log('Invalid credential');
      }
  }
```

In my `login.html`

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm"  novalidate >
    <!-- Login form -->
    <div class="list-form">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>
          <ion-icon name="mail" item-start class="text-white"></ion-icon>
          Email
        </ion-label>

        <ion-input type="email" value="" formControlName ="email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>
          <ion-icon name="lock" item-start class="text-white"></ion-icon>
          Password
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" value="" formControlName ="password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </div>

    <p text-right ion-text color="white" tappable (click)="forgotPass()"><strong>Forgot Password?</strong></p>

    <div>
      <button type="submit" ion-button icon-start block color="dark" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid"  (click)="login()">
        <ion-icon name="log-in"></ion-icon>
        SIGN IN
      </button>

    </div>

  </form>
```

Can anyone please tell me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: not sure try removing novalidate and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
  password: new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(8)]),
  email: new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(".+\@.+\..+")])
});
```

Try:

```
this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(".+\@.+\..+")],
   password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]]
});
```

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked. Your original implementation should have worked based on what I read on the Angular FormGroup documentation, but the Ionic samples use formBuilder instead: https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/forms/ The odd thing is, formBuilder is just syntactic sugar for creating the FormGroup.

Comment: yes i noticed. But those seems very complicated me to at first since i am nobbie :D
so i choose to do this way just like normal website form :D

Answer (score 0):

For those who are also seeking solution to this answer , here is the complete code for my login form

In `login.ts`

```
import {FormBuilder,FormGroup,Validators,FormControl,AbstractControl} from "@angular/forms";

export class LoginPage {
  loginForm:FormGroup;
  email:AbstractControl;
  password:AbstractControl;
  responseData:any;
  constructor(public nav: NavController,
              public forgotCtrl: AlertController,
              public menu: MenuController,
              public formbuilder:FormBuilder
  ) {

    this.loginForm = formbuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(".+\@.+\..+")]],
      password : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]]

    })
    this.email = this.loginForm.controls['email'];
    this.password = this.loginForm.controls['password']


    this.menu.swipeEnable(false);
  }



  //login and go to home page
  login() {

    if(this.loginForm.valid ){
      console.log(this.loginForm.value);
      //Do your validation

      }else{
        console.log('Invalid credential');
      }
  }

 }
```